# Text editor for writing film screenplays

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

I'm looking at [this page on GitHub](https://github.com/snaptoken/kilo-tutorial/tree/v1.0.0beta1) with the source code to *build your own text editor*.

I want a text editor for movie script writing.

What can I use for this purpose on Ubuntu?

Comment: But isn't "the code" already in github?

Comment: I wanna this 'light like a text editor' for write screenplay, just with .txt

Comment: I'm a writer, I need to use this on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Will any Markdown editor be enough to solve your problem? You can try ReText as starting point.

Comment: What are your requirements to a text editor ? Techically, you can use vim, gedit of LibreOffice Writer .. or any other editor .. they all allow you to enter text, format (more or less), edit and save it. What else do you need ?

Comment: I've hace some txt screenplay exported from Celtx, FadeIn (itś free but have an eternum 'pop up' I need to write without make 'clic off' a windows, o think in the right format, tabulating 5 times to the CAST 4 times to dialogue... to have the space on a page.

Comment: programmer on a 'text editor' have al bottom the menu select to make this, separate, generate the space, but it's for developers only. https://yadi.sk/d/5EwshtbMRiEBRw

Comment: And I was OK IF i'm the only who read my scripts. You save your codes online?

Comment: So far four close votes already for being not about Ubuntu have been cast on this ordinary software recommendation question. This is an ordinary software recommendation question, and ordinary software recommendation questions are not off topic at Ask Ubuntu. This impending close vote decision will be reversed.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/0SdF1xy_6N25Dg

Comment: Please see on link whtat I wanna do. Writting it's an automatic thing when you know what to write ..see, and speak. (screenplaying talking)

Comment: IF I have to thing 'move this, press the TAB to 'I'm kicking off' from the board (keyboard) to think  other matter that it's outside the story. I'll be worry about the format of the screenplay and not from the content.

Comment: There's a lot of free software that I used before. scripped Writer / Celtx / Final Draft / Scriptum / Plotbot / Cinergy Script Editor / Zhura / some of them, make an upgrade, other lost on a highway. (Think if you have to write a CODE and everytime somebody decide to quit his own project, the user need to change the .foutain .frt .celtx .extension and not always work to export to pdf and import to the new program. (that happen when you quit) Please, read with good vibes.

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon Storywriter](https://storywriter.amazon.com/tutorials) is a free screenwriting tool distributed by Amazon as a [web application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-storywriter/hmcnhpcghhifadgblhkonelnmbenkeep) for Google Chrome and Chromium web browser. This app can be used offline even when there is no connection to the internet.

Storywriter automatically formats your screenplay as you type - you don't need to tell Storywriter what kind of element you want to use. Each element gets formatted when you move to the next line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. you trust in 'sync' from others? Do you check the Amazon? I Lost a work for use other vision.

Comment: I need OFFLINE. Amazon turned Cloud. 'OffLine' = Save Storage

Comment: I Lost with: Mega. Facebook. Zenkit. Google. Apple. ++more

Comment: You save your CODES online?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TEX](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlive) and for instance this package:

[**screen­play**](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/screenplay?lang=en) – A class file to type­set screen­plays

Look at this [test-pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/screenplay/test.pdf).